# Range.ClearContents interferes with a paste macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a question about clearing and pasting a selection from another workbook.

I am trying to make a macro that clears the old data I have in a tab and copies the data I have on my clipboard from another excel workbook in it's stead.

I kept getting an error before I noticed what was wrong. When the macro runs the clearing part, it cancels my selection/copy data I had, so the pasting part does not work. does anybody know how to circumvent it? I can't reference the excel where the data is coming from directly because it varies every time.

the code I use now for the clearing:

```
Sub clearData()

Worksheets("ZRFI08TW").Range("A5:M5000").ClearContents

End Sub
```

The coded i use now for the pasting of the data (i know its not the best, but trying different things before i noticed the conflict ended up with this one):

```
Sub copyData()

ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Select
SendKeys "^v"
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Whatever you do, probably will clear selection. You could paste the data into a new workbook, clear, and then copy/paste the data from new workbook into destiny, and close new workbook without saving changes

Comment: Why don't you copy, paste, and clear in the end? Think if any other order would be possible.

Comment: Why does it have to be exactly copy, clear, paste? If you can explain more the background, maybe there is a workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

I can come up with two options, following the logic of your code for using `SendKeys "^v"` for a paste:

- Using - `Worksheets("ZRFI08TW").Range("A5:M5000") = ""`
- Assigning the `Selection` to a range and then selecting this range again and pasting it:

---

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Selection
Worksheets("ZRFI08TW").Range("A5:M5000").ClearContents
myRange.Select
myRange.Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Select
SendKeys "^v"
```

But there should be a way better way to achieve what you are looking for. And as I am mentioning `.Select`, I feel an urge to mention this one - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).